# Как вставить русский текст в HTML элемент браузера?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Получаю мой текст:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://mypage/mytext.php")
page_source = response.read()
page_source
"({code:'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc!'});"
```

Потом надо вставить текст в нужное поле браузера:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("mytext").send_keys(page_source)
```

Как осуществить ?
Спасибо

Comment: Можно расширить вопрос? Что за driver? Какая это библиотека? В чём, собственно, заключается проблема? Что говорит интерпретатор? Если он ничего не говорит, то что выводится в "браузере"? В общем, если можно, дайте примеры того, что Вы получаете и того, что Вы хотите получить.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

Comment: Так дополните сам вопрос -- в нём и напишете что да библиотеки, как подключаете.